# Can someone help me figure out why my app is crashing when running on iPad. Culprit is unsupported framework - iAd

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, sdk

I have read plenty of questions and answers here about weak linking, checking if a class is valid before executing code etc.  My app is basically finished and ready (at least I thought it was, my first app for the store) but I need to fix this problem so my app natively runs on the iPad.

The error I'm receiving is the following:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (ADBannerView)'

My question to you pro's out there is, I am setting some IBOutlet properties in my class header.  For example;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ADBannerView *tollBanner;

Is this property causing the problem when trying to run the app on the iPad?  I have added some conditionals in my viewDidLoad method if the ADBannerView class not nil.  Also in my dealloc method I'm releasing these ADBannerView objects.

I would appreciate any help with this and TIA.

T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's possible the creation of the object is derived from a nib/xib.

if your nib/xib requires custom classes which are available on some platforms/OS versions, you must either:

1) add it programmatically

-or-

2) create multiple nibs (for each localization), then load the nib specific for the current runtime

the former sounds more simple, in most cases.

(ps: the callstack would help)

Comment: Justin thanks for the tip.  Looks like I'll redo things and add it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [iOS documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) for `ADBannerView`:

> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

The iPad's iOS version is currently 3.2* so you will not be able to use this class on the iPad.

*4.2 was recently seeded to developers (if the media reports are accurate) but your app will crash on iDevices running iOS earlier than 4.0 regardless of the hardware.

Comment: fbrereto yes I understand < 4.0 the iAd framework is not supported.  I have weak linked and setup conditionals in my implementation but my question was is the crash because of the references I'm making in my header file.

Comment: @tg2007: The issue is that you are trying to unarchive something that contains an `ADBannerView` as part of the archive. When the unarchival code runs across this reference it tries to make an instantiation of the unsupported class, and you're crashing. I believe there are macros in `Availability.h` you can use to #if-out the offending code.